# How to find maximum likelihood parameter estimates for a custom bivariate distribution?

Tags: distributions, parameters

this is univariate distribution

```
dist= ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 -  E^-(\[Lambda]*x))^\[Alpha]}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]},Assumptions -> {\[Lambda] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0}];
```

this is data

```
data = {74, 57, 48, 29, 502, 12, 70, 21, 29, 386, 59, 27, 153, 26, 326}
```

i used this code to get parameters

```
 mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, dist, ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

and used this code to get -L

```
LogLikelihood[dist, data] /. mle
```

how i do it with this bivariate copula distribution and data to get this results

```
dist1= ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 -  E^-(\[Lambda]*x))^\[Alpha]}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]},Assumptions -> {\[Lambda] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0}];
dist2= ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 -  E^-(\[Lambda]*x))^\[Alpha]}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]},Assumptions -> {\[Lambda] > 0, \[Alpha] > 0}];

bidist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM",\[Gamma]}, {dist1, dist2}];


data = {{2, 6.5}, {2, 6.5}, {2.1, 10.1}, {2.2, 7.2}, {2.2, 7.6}, {2.2,
 7.9}, {2.2, 8.5}, {2.2, 9.1}, {2.2, 9.6}, {2.2, 9.6}, {2.2, 
10.7}, {2.3, 9.6}, {2.4, 7.3}, {2.4, 7.9}, {2.4, 7.9}, {2.4, 
9.1}, {2.4, 9.3}, {2.5, 7.9}, {2.5, 8.6}, {2.5, 8.8}, {2.5, 
8.8}, {2.5, 9.3}, {2.5, 11}, {2.5, 12.7}, {2.5, 12.7}, {2.6, 
7.7}, {2.6, 8.3}, {2.6, 9.4}, {2.6, 9.4}, {2.6, 10.5}, {2.6, 
11.5}, {2.7, 8}, {2.7, 9}, {2.7, 9.6}, {2.7, 9.6}, {2.7, 
9.8}, {2.7, 10.4}, {2.7, 11.1}, {2.7, 12}, {2.7, 12.5}, {2.8, 
9.1}, {2.8, 10}, {2.8, 10.2}, {2.8, 11.4}, {2.8, 12}, {2.8, 
13.3}, {2.8, 13.5}, {2.9, 9.4}, {2.9, 10.1}, {2.9, 10.6}, {2.9, 
11.3}, {2.9, 11.8}, {3, 10}, {3, 10.4}, {3, 10.6}, {3, 11.6}, {3, 
12.2}, {3, 12.4}, {3, 12.7}, {3, 13.3}, {3, 13.8}, {3.1, 
9.9}, {3.1, 11.5}, {3.1, 12.1}, {3.1, 12.5}, {3.1, 13}, {3.1, 
14.3}, {3.2, 11.6}, {3.2, 11.9}, {3.2, 12.3}, {3.2, 13}, {3.2, 
13.5}, {3.2, 13.6}, {3.3, 11.5}, {3.3, 12}, {3.3, 14.1}, {3.3, 
14.9}, {3.3, 15.4}, {3.4, 11.2}, {3.4, 12.2}, {3.4, 12.4}, {3.4, 
12.8}, {3.4, 14.4}, {3.5, 11.7}, {3.5, 12.9}, {3.5, 15.6}, {3.5, 
15.7}, {3.5, 17.2}, {3.6, 11.8}, {3.6, 13.3}, {3.6, 14.8}, {3.6, 
15}, {3.7, 11}, {3.8, 14.8}, {3.8, 16.8}, {3.9, 14.4}, {3.9, 
20.5}};
```

now i want to calculate mle

```
     mle = FindDistributionParameters[data, bidist , ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

but i get error like this
[image]

and i can't get -L
or pvalue

```
DistributionFitTest[data, bidist /. mle, {"TestDataTable", "KolmogorovSmirnov"}]
```

Comment: "But I get error" - what error do you get exactly? Leaving those details out forces potential helpers to copy and run your code to even find out if they can help. On the other hand, you may be lucky and one of the readers will know the solution from your error code alone, if you include it!

Comment: You have an error in the code:  `"FGM,\[Gamma]"` should be `{"FGM", \[Gamma]}`.  In addition, your proposed bivariate distribution has identical marginals.  However, the marginal means and variances are wildly different.

Comment: Giving just 4 data points (`{{2, 6.5}, {2, 6.5}, {2.1, 10.1}, {2.2, 7.2}}`) to estimate 3 parameters is not going to work.

Comment: I gave more than 4 data points but same results JimB

Comment: You need to show what you did and not have us guessing.  This appears to be a pattern and you could likely lose a lot of interest from folks who could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I think one needs to construct the log likelihood "from scratch" and use a high `WorkingPrecision`.

```
(* Data *)
data = {{2, 6.5}, {2, 6.5}, {2.1, 10.1}, {2.2, 7.2}, {2.2, 7.6}, {2.2,
     7.9}, {2.2, 8.5}, {2.2, 9.1}, {2.2, 9.6}, {2.2, 9.6}, {2.2, 
    10.7}, {2.3, 9.6}, {2.4, 7.3}, {2.4, 7.9}, {2.4, 7.9}, {2.4, 
    9.1}, {2.4, 9.3}, {2.5, 7.9}, {2.5, 8.6}, {2.5, 8.8}, {2.5, 
    8.8}, {2.5, 9.3}, {2.5, 11}, {2.5, 12.7}, {2.5, 12.7}, {2.6, 
    7.7}, {2.6, 8.3}, {2.6, 9.4}, {2.6, 9.4}, {2.6, 10.5}, {2.6, 
    11.5}, {2.7, 8}, {2.7, 9}, {2.7, 9.6}, {2.7, 9.6}, {2.7, 
    9.8}, {2.7, 10.4}, {2.7, 11.1}, {2.7, 12}, {2.7, 12.5}, {2.8, 
    9.1}, {2.8, 10}, {2.8, 10.2}, {2.8, 11.4}, {2.8, 12}, {2.8, 
    13.3}, {2.8, 13.5}, {2.9, 9.4}, {2.9, 10.1}, {2.9, 10.6}, {2.9, 
    11.3}, {2.9, 11.8}, {3, 10}, {3, 10.4}, {3, 10.6}, {3, 11.6}, {3, 
    12.2}, {3, 12.4}, {3, 12.7}, {3, 13.3}, {3, 13.8}, {3.1, 
    9.9}, {3.1, 11.5}, {3.1, 12.1}, {3.1, 12.5}, {3.1, 13}, {3.1, 
    14.3}, {3.2, 11.6}, {3.2, 11.9}, {3.2, 12.3}, {3.2, 13}, {3.2, 
    13.5}, {3.2, 13.6}, {3.3, 11.5}, {3.3, 12}, {3.3, 14.1}, {3.3, 
    14.9}, {3.3, 15.4}, {3.4, 11.2}, {3.4, 12.2}, {3.4, 12.4}, {3.4, 
    12.8}, {3.4, 14.4}, {3.5, 11.7}, {3.5, 12.9}, {3.5, 15.6}, {3.5, 
    15.7}, {3.5, 17.2}, {3.6, 11.8}, {3.6, 13.3}, {3.6, 14.8}, {3.6, 
    15}, {3.7, 11}, {3.8, 14.8}, {3.8, 16.8}, {3.9, 14.4}, {3.9, 
    20.5}};
data = Rationalize[data, 0];

(* Define distributions *)
dist1 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 - E^-(λ1*x))^α1}, {x, 0, ∞},
   Assumptions -> {λ1 > 0, α1 > 0}];
dist2 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 - E^-(λ2*x))^α2}, {x, 0, ∞},
   Assumptions -> {λ2 > 0, α2 > 0}];
bidist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", γ}, {dist1, dist2}];
```

Now construct the log of the likelihood and use some substitutions in an attempt to speed things up.  I gave up on using `LogLikelihood` directly.

```
(* The substitutions are an attempt to simplify the resulting log likelihood *)
logpdf = (Log[PDF[bidist, {x, y}]] // PiecewiseExpand)[[2]];
logpdf = logpdf //. Log[u_ v_] -> Log[u] + Log[v] //. Log[u_^v_] -> v Log[u]
logL = Total[logpdf /. {x -> data[[All, 1]], y -> data[[All, 2]]}];

mle = FindMaximum[{logL, λ1 > 0 && λ2 > 0 && α1 > 0 && α2 > 0 && -1 < γ < 1},
  {λ1, λ2, α1, α2, γ}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* {-271.80470974521206383075696322790604898437737424471, 
{λ1 -> 2.4941182035060283311914526300852320136344602902781,
 λ2 -> 0.47825679807006947144544091632892697088138495905157,
 α1 -> 765.98664215659951906278158670015743663123546664348,
 α2 -> 122.76925777452731498490642356544790410817809336203,
 γ -> 0.99999999999999999999999999999925884158661728362410}} *)

Show[ContourPlot[PDF[bidist /. mle[[2]], {x, y}],
  {x, 1.5, 4.5}, {y, 5, 22}, ContourShading -> None],
 ListPlot[data]]
```

[image: Data and estimated bivariate density]

I don't think a statistical test of goodness-of-fit is necessary:  the fit is not very good.