# Estimate parameters from random samples drawn from a copula distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, parameters

I defined a copula distribution as follows:

```
dist1 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 - E^-(λ1*x))^α1}, {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {λ1 > 0, α1 > 0}];
dist2 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", (1 - E^-(λ2*x))^α2}, {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {λ2 > 0, α2 > 0}];

bidist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", γ}, {dist1, dist2}]
```

I then used `RandomVariate` to generate 3 samples of size 4:

```
data = RandomVariate[bidist /. {λ1 -> 2, λ2 -> 0.47, α1 -> 5, α2 -> 3, γ -> 0.9}, {3, 4}]
```

and the output is as follows:

```
{{{1.4148, 6.38279}, {2.01691, 3.35961}, {0.880359, 5.34531}, {1.72377, 2.80598}}, {{0.786384, 1.69397}, {1.41287, 4.21653}, {0.688413, 0.937421}, {1.5756, 3.38058}}, {{1.17281,  4.39094}, {1.74028, 5.39881}, {0.776455, 1.16388}, {0.937518,   3.21342}}}
```

I want to calculate parameters for each sample of 3 samples
because I want to do a simulation as in the illustration below:
[image: picparameters]

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried towards your goal of calculating those values?

Comment: I used. Code. From here [link]https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271887/how-to-find-maximum-likelihood-parameter-estimates-for-a-custom-bivariate-distri.  Or here.       https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271912/what-is-wrong-in-my-code-for-calculate-parameters-bivariate-distribution  but my problem  is put each x from each sample to x  and y from each sample to y in the maximum likelihood or distribution until I can calculate parameter for each sample from 3 of samples as a list .

Comment: Why would you want to estimate 5 parameters ($\gamma$, $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\alpha_1$, and $\alpha_2$) from just 4 data points?  And why would you need to generate 3 independent samples of size 4?

Comment: I want to generalize to any sample size and write it to any bivariate custom distribution with copula

Comment: But a sample size of anything 4 or smaller cannot find a unique solution to the maximum likelihood equations.  I think you'll need to state why this question is any different from some of your previous questions or it's likely to be closed.

Comment: I want to know how I calculate it, I can put sample size as 15 element no problem in it

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271887/how-to-find-maximum-likelihood-parameter-estimates-for-a-custom-bivariate-distri gives you the solution so this question is a duplicate.